# Keep data in inputs using ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I created an application with 2 steps. On each step user should add some data in inputs.
After clicking on button `2`, the user changes the step. I want to create a scenario:

1. User fill form from first step and after that click on button `2`
2. When user clicks on button `1`, the first form should appear with the data that was added previously.

```js
const [state, seState] = useState(1);

  const one = () => {
    seState(1);
  };

  const two = () => {
    seState(2);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {state === 1 ? <Form1 /> : <Form2 />}
      <button onClick={one}>1</button>
      <button onClick={two}>2</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd480-forked-kdyyn?file=/index.js:252-615 
Question: Has ant design this build in functionality? How to keep data from each step, and when user will switch the steps the data should be inside inputs?

Comment: You basically need to share the state between two forms, so you can store these state in the parent component. You can learn more about this from the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

To keep the data, no matter ant or not, you would need to make a choice. Firstly you can keep all the forms in the DOM and use CSS to hide them ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd480-forked-zliib)):

```
  const [state, seState] = useState(1);

  const one = () => {
    seState(1);
  };

  const two = () => {
    seState(2);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={state === 1 ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
        <Form1 />
      </div>
      <div style={state === 2 ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
        <Form2 />
      </div>
      <button onClick={one}>1</button>
      <button onClick={two}>2</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Secondly you can choose to re-fill the form values every time you do `setState` by keeping the data in a shared store such as redux or `userReducer`. I choose the first approach for simple forms that do not require too much logic and don't have large DOMs. Second approach can be a better choice in dynamic and complex data scenarios.

Comment: could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574664/cant-download-a-file-in-reactjs